# Download and Save Video to Camera Roll

Tags: ios, swift, video, alamofire, camera-roll

This seems to be something that should be very straight forward based on all the examples and docs I've read, but I am still unable to get this to work for some strange reason.

I am using Alamofire Frame work to download a video from instagram.  Once downloaded, I then want to save the video to the Camera Roll.  Here is my code to Download the video and save to disk:

```
let destination: (NSURL, NSHTTPURLResponse) -> (NSURL) = {
            (temporaryURL, response) in

            if let directoryURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0] as? NSURL {

                let finalPath = directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(Scripts.dateToString2(date: NSDate())).\(response.suggestedFilename!)")
                InstagramEngine.downloadMediaPath = finalPath

                Scripts.log("Final Path >> \(finalPath)")

                return finalPath
            }

            return temporaryURL
        }

        let request = Alamofire.download(.GET, self.videoURL, destination)

        request.response { _, response, data, error in

                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(kMediaDownloadComplete, object: nil)

        }
```

Once the download is complete, the Notification is triggered which calls this function to save it to Camera Roll:

```
UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(InstagramEngine.downloadMediaPath.URLString, self, Selector("video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:"), nil)
```

Everything is being called based on my log statements and no errors occured.  Even didFinishSavingWithError is being called successfully for the UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum and I confirmed no errors found.  But when I go check the camera roll, I still see no video saved there.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is a bug related to `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum` and the format `mp4`, which is the format used by Instagram.

There is a helper method called `UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum` to help indicate whether a video is compatible with the method `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum`. This returns `false` for the video downloaded from Instagram.

---

Luckily it is still possible to store the videos into the camera roll. This is possible using `ALAssetsLibrary`. I've tried to take your sample code and adapt it to use `ALAssetsLibrary`, hopefully this can help you to get it working.

```
import AssetsLibrary

...
...

func downloadVideoToCameraRoll() {

    // Local variable pointing to the local file path for the downloaded video
    var localFileUrl: String?

    // A closure for generating the local file path for the downloaded video. This will be pointing to the Documents directory with a unique UDID file name.
    let destination: (NSURL, NSHTTPURLResponse) -> (NSURL) = {
        (temporaryURL, response) in

        if let directoryURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0] as? NSURL {
            let finalPath = directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(NSUUID()).\(response.suggestedFilename!)")
            localFileUrl = finalPath.absoluteString
            return finalPath
        }

        return temporaryURL
    }

    // The media post which should be downloaded
    let postURL = NSURL(string: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/" + "952201134785549382_250131908" + "?access_token=" + InstagramEngine.sharedEngine().accessToken)!

    // Then some magic happens that turns the postURL into the videoURL, which is the actual url of the video media:
    let videoURL = NSURL(string: "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfp1/t50.2886-16/11104555_1603400416544760_416259564_s.mp4")!

    // Download starts
    let request = Alamofire.download(.GET, videoURL, destination)

    // Completion handler for the download
    request.response { (request, response, data, error) -> Void in
        if let path = localFileUrl {
            let isVideoCompatible = UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(path)
            println("bool: \(isVideoCompatible)") // This logs out "bool: false"

            let library = ALAssetsLibrary()

            library.writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(NSURL(string: path), completionBlock: { (url, error) -> Void in
                // Done! Go check your camera roll
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to download and save video, using Alamofire. Code is in Swift 4. Note that we need to use `Photos` framework because `AssetsLibrary` was deprecated

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import Photos

/// Download and save video to camera roll
final class VideoFetcher {
  private let fileManager: FileManager

  init(fileManager: FileManager = FileManager.default) {
    self.fileManager = fileManager
  }

  func downloadAndSave(videoUrl: URL, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    let destination: (URL, HTTPURLResponse) -> (URL, DownloadRequest.DownloadOptions) = {
      tempUrl, response in

      let option = DownloadRequest.DownloadOptions()
      let finalUrl = tempUrl.deletingPathExtension().appendingPathExtension(videoUrl.pathExtension)
      return (finalUrl, option)
    }

    Alamofire.download(videoUrl, to: destination)
      .response(completionHandler: { [weak self] response in
        guard response.error == nil,
          let destinationUrl = response.destinationURL else {
            completion(false)
            return
        }

        self?.save(videoFileUrl: destinationUrl, completion: completion)
      })
  }

  private func save(videoFileUrl: URL, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
      PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: videoFileUrl)
    }, completionHandler: { succeeded, error in
      guard error == nil, succeeded else {
        completion(false)
        return
      }

      completion(true)
    })
  }
}
```